# Spearman-like correlation when X and Y are interchangeable?

Tags: mixed-model, outliers, paired-data, spearman-rho

I have some data consisting of pairs of brothers, and I want to look at correlation within the pairs. There is no logical basis for determining which one will be "X" and which one will be "Y".

So, for example:

```
X | Y     X | Y
-----     -----
1 | 5     1 | 5   
2 | 6     6 | 2
3 | 7     3 | 7
4 | 8     8 | 4
rho=1     rho=-0.6
```

Both tables show the same pairs, but in the table on the right I've flipped which brother is X and which is Y for two of the pairs.

I have seen this issue addressed in the past with sibling data by using a mixed model and calculating an Intraclass Correlation Coefficient. But mixed models aren't likely to be a solution here, because my data has some extreme outliers (and the outliers are important, so excluding them would not be appropriate).

So is there something non-parametric like a Spearman correlation that can work with data like this where there is no meaningful way to decide which brother is "X" and which one is "Y"?

Comment: What is the purpose of your study ? What is your analysis ? what are you estimating with rho estimates ?

Comment: I am looking at several different continuous traits in the brothers. The goal is to be able to say something like “Brothers tend to have high correlation with each-other on traits A, B, and C, but much lower correlation for traits D and E.”

Comment: what is X and Y ?  what is rho - ICC ?  The intraclass correlation. How do you measure traits etc. The design of study and data is not indicated.

Comment: X would be one brother’s value on a trait, Y would be the other brother’s value on the same trait. Rho would be a Spearman correlation coefficient, but as I show here, it isn’t appropriate to the data because there is no logical basis for deciding which brother is X and which is Y, and if you switch some of them rho changes drastically. So I need something that would work like ICC instead, but that is non-parametric because my data is going to have extreme outliers.